# Accessing Path Variable in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I need to access Path variable in eclipse , tried statements:

```
System.out.println("${env_var:ECLIPSE_HOME}");
System.out.println("${ECLIPSE_HOME}");
```

but unsuccessful , can someone please let me know how to do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would like to use environment variables in the Eclipse dialogs like Linked Resources?  Or you would like to use Path Variables in a java application launched from eclipse?  Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```

Comment: actually i am trying to access Path Variables set from eclipse by navigating to File->Properties->Resources->Linked Resources , by using System.out.println(System.getenv("ECLIPSE_HOME")); getting null